# wp_get_attachment_image not working wordpress to show blog post image

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress and trying to create a blog landing page to show the most recent blog posts. So far so good but I am having difficulties showing the blog image in the image tag. I am able to obtain the postId by using `get_the_id` function. I was also able to get the date of the post by using `the_date` function.

However, I cannot get the `wp_get_attachment_image` function to show the image of the blog post.

Please see my code below.

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?> 

<?php while ($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post(); ?>
    <div class="blog">
      <img src="wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID() ); ">
      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
      <p><?php the_date(); ?></p>
      <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></p>
    </div>

    <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure post id is equal to attachement_id ? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/

Comment: if not do you know how I can get this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the following function `the_post_thumbnail()` and echo the result within an image tag

```
<img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail();?>">
```

The following code worked.

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' ); ?> 

<?php while ($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post(); ?>
    <div class="blog">
      <img src="wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID() ); ">
      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
      <p><?php the_date(); ?></p>
      <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></p>
    </div>
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for get the attached image.

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');?>">
```

Comment: that is passing array into the image src

Answer (score 0):

The function `wp_get_attachment_image` is waiting for `attachement_id`.

See below in wp, how we get all attachments from a post :

```
<?php if ( $post->post_type == 'data-design' && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
        $attachments = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
        ) );

        if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                $class = "post-attachment mime-" . sanitize_title( $attachment->post_mime_type );
                $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );
                echo '<li class="' . $class . ' data-design-thumbnail">' . $thumbimg . '</li>';
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: but is `get_the_id` not getting the id?

Comment: `get_the_id` may get `false` if post isn't set.

Comment: do you know how I can get this id? it isn't very clear to me from the above!

Comment: One post has many attachments. we can get all ids in loop like the above.